# Changing Background Color in Active Cell via Custom Menu in Google Docs via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a table within a Google Document (NOT sheets). I have created a custom menu and it will have a list of options. The goal is when the user selects one of the options, it will change the background color of the active cell (determined by where the cursor is). I attempted the below code and it ran with no errors, but it does not change the background color. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
function onOpen() {

      var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();

      ui.createMenu('Change Colors')
      .addItem('Low', 'LowFunction')
      .addToUi();
    }

    function LowFunction() {
      DocumentApp.getUi()
      var document = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

      var SelectedCell = document.getCursor().getElement();
      var range = SelectedCell.setBackgroundColor('#ffffff');
    }
```

For some additional information, if I add the following line of code:

```
var SelectedCell = document.getTables()[1].getCell(1,0).setBackgroundColor('#000000');
```

It will change the background color of a particular cell...but I just need this code to change the color of the currently selected cell if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to change the background color of the cell when the cursor position is staying in the cell.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification point:

- In order to check whether the cursor position is in a cell, it checks the parent of `document.getCursor().getElement()`. Because the element type is a paragraph when the cursor is staying in a cell.

#### Modified script:

```
function LowFunction() {
  var document = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var cursor = document.getCursor().getElement();
  var SelectedCell = cursor.getParent();
  if (SelectedCell.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE_CELL) {
    SelectedCell.asTableCell().setBackgroundColor("#808080");
  }
}
```

- In this srcript, the background color of cell is changed to gray color.

#### References:

- [getParent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#getparent)
- [asTableCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/container-element#astablecell)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Ah, that's what I was missing! This is exactly what I needed and it works perfectly. Thanks so much for the thorough explanation!

Comment: @hunter21188 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.